# How to print result set associated in only one cell inside an html table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

My db is composed two tables **User** and **Friends**

- An **`User`** have many **`Friends`**

I need to show the following table view

[image]

I queried both tables with an INNER JOIN as follows

```
SELECT usr.FirstName, usr.Phone, usr.Email, fri.FirstName AS friendName
FROM User AS usr
INNER JOIN Friends AS fri
WHERE fri.idUser = usr.idUser
```

Because many **`Friends`** have an **`User`**, **`Friends`** have the control how many results set will be returned.

Output:

```
{
  "FirstName" : "jose", "Phone" : 123, "Email": "jose@jose.com", "friendName" : "Pedro",
  "FirstName" : "jose", "Phone" : 123, "Email": "jose@jose.com", "friendName" : "Juan", // Same user, with another friend
}
```

The result set is correct, but i don't achieve figure out how to print it like the table view shown previously from Javascript or any language programming code that requested that query

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Do you have a userId somewhere in your users table? Can you fetch it with your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate, with **HTML** you can just use [unordered lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_lists.htm) `<ul>` for `Friends` column

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>E-Mail</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jose</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>jose@jose.com</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>Pedro</li>
          <li>Juan</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Felipe</td>
      <td>456</td>
      <td>felipe@felipe.com</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>Carlos</li>
          <li>Jose</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To use **Javascript** let's assume you have `users` array, you can loop on it and generate the `<table>` like this:

```js
let users = [
    {"userId": 1, "FirstName": "jose", "Phone": 123, "Email": "jose@jose.com", "friendName": "Pedro"},
    {"userId": 1, "FirstName": "jose", "Phone": 123, "Email": "jose@jose.com", "friendName": "Juan"},
    {"userId": 2, "FirstName": "felipe", "Phone": 456, "Email": "felipe@felipe.com", "friendName": "Carlos"},
    {"userId": 2, "FirstName": "felipe", "Phone": 456, "Email": "felipe@felipe.com", "friendName": "Jose"}
];

// To combine friends of the same user in an array at property friendNames
let usersWithFriends = {};
for (let user of users) {
  let index = 'user' + user.userId;
  if (typeof usersWithFriends[index] === 'undefined') {
    usersWithFriends[index] = user;
  } else {
    if (typeof usersWithFriends[index].friendNames === 'undefined') {
      usersWithFriends[index].friendNames = [usersWithFriends[index].friendName];
      delete usersWithFriends[index].friendName;
    }

    usersWithFriends[index].friendNames.push(user.friendName);
  }
}

let tbodyHTML = '';
// For the # column
let no = 1;

for (let user in usersWithFriends) {
  let userDetails;
  if (usersWithFriends.hasOwnProperty(user)) {
    userDetails = usersWithFriends[user];
  }
  tbodyHTML += '<tr>';
  tbodyHTML += `<td>${no++}</td>`;
  tbodyHTML += `<td>${userDetails.FirstName}</td>`;
  tbodyHTML += `<td>${userDetails.Phone}</td>`;
  tbodyHTML += `<td>${userDetails.Email}</td>`;
  tbodyHTML += '<td><ul>';
  for (let friendName of userDetails.friendNames) {
    tbodyHTML += `<li>${friendName}</li>`;
  }
  tbodyHTML += '</td></ul>';
  tbodyHTML += '</tr>';
}

document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = tbodyHTML;
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>E-Mail</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,I see the tag you mark this question as mysql, so it is  very simple to implete the html output when use mysql command with a `--html` config. just like below:

```
mysql -u username -p password -D database --html -e"select * from your_table_name limit 10" > data_result.html
```

when you open the above html file `data_result.html` by browser, you'd get the print style you want.
[image]